# Check to see if user input is in a certain range in Ruby

Tags: ruby, if-statement, range

If the user types anything other than a number, and any number besides a number in range of 1 - 32, I need it to ask for input again.

It's giving me an error when I use if cut_number in 1..32

```
def cut_the_deck
  puts "You get to cut the deck to make it even more random!"
  puts "Type a number between 1 and 32. That's where the deck will be cut!"
    cut_number = gets.chomp
    cut_number = cut_number.to_i
      if cut_number in 1..32
        puts "Number in range"
      else
        puts "Number NOT in range"
        cut_the_deck
      end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [between?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Comparable.html#method-i-between-3F):

```
if cut_number.between?(1,32) #=> true or false
```

Comment: Link to [Comparable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Comparable.html#method-i-between-3F) rdoc.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could do:

```
if (1..32).include?(cut_number)
```

Comment: That certainly works but `between?` just reads a bit more natural to me.